# How to select a:hover that's not in a certain selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I would like to style `a` elements that are not in a certain id. For example, let's say this is my HTML:

```
<div id="boat">
   <a href="#">I'm in a boat! ☻</a>
</div>
<a href="#">☹</a>
```

Now, let's say I only want to style the `a` element that's not in a boat. I expected something similar to `a:hover:not(#boat a)` to work, but alas, it doesn't. Is there a way I can do what I want to do?

Comment: Unfortunately `:not()` only accepts a single simple selector as an argument. Here, `#boat a` represents two simple selectors combined with the descendant selector, with `a` being the key selector. Your best bet is to use jQuery - I like Marcus Whybrow's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to jQuery selectors `a:hover` will select all the `a` elements which have the CSS pseudo class `:hover` applied to it (i.e. `a` elements which are currently being hovered over with the mouse).

This is the selection process, and **not the styling selection**, to select the elements you are talking about, try this instead:

```
$('a:not(#boat a)')
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/AMWhU/

If a hover jQuery effect is waht you are after the once you have made the selection just bind the event as usual:

```
$('a:not(#boat a)').hover(function() {});
```

Comment: Since it doesn't seem like I can do this in normal CSS, I'm going to go ahead and use this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Links not within that `div#id` will have `.closest('div#id').length === 0`, and since 0 is false, you can select on the opposite of those as follows to style those links:

```
$('a').hover(function(e){
    if (!$(this).closest('div#boat').length) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
});
```

[**Here's an example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuMWy/)

Comment: You should make the selection correctly before binding a handler to every single `a` tag, thus reducing the set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a negating attribute selector ('!=').  Given (mostly) your original html:

```
<script src="/Users/kburton/Downloads/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
    </script>
<div id="boat">
  <a href="#">I'm in a boat!</a>
</div>
<div id='car'>
  <a href="#">I'm in a car!</a>
</div>
<a href="#">I'm not in the boat!</a>
```

At the javascript console, running:

```
$('[id!="boat"] > a')
```

Looks for all nodes that do not have the id 'boat', with an anchor child.