# Randomize logo color and change CSS link color accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This function randomizes the logo of the site. I'm trying to make a conditional statement that changes the a:hover color accordingly.

If the blue color is chosen the `a:hover, .current-menu-item` should have `color: blue;`.

What is the best way of implementing this?

```
function logoChange() { 
var description = new Array ();
description[0] = "images/logos/blue.png";
description[1] = "images/logos/green.png";
description[2] = "images/logos/orange.png";
description[3] = "images/logos/purple.png";
description[4] = "images/logos/red.png";
description[5] = "images/logos/yellow.png";
var size = description.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
document.getElementById('logo').src=description[x];    
}
window.onload=logoChange;


if (logo blue is chosen)
  {
  <style>a:hover, .current-menu-item {color: blue;}</style>
  }

elseif (logo green is chosen)
  {
  <style>a:hover, .current-menu-item {color: green;}</style>
  }

and so on...
```

Comment: The best way would be to have *classes* defined for your different color schemes, and apply the class to the *body* element.  Example: `.blue a:hover {color: blue;}` and `.green a:hover {color:green;}`, etc.  Then, when the logo is selected, just apply that class to the body element, and boom, you're done.

Comment: Yes, this seems overly complicated. Make a div, then set up classes that will then assign the appropriate image and colors and hover states in your CSS. Then your JS just needs to apply a random class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was created an array of all the possible colors that it can be. Notice how the index of the colors matches the index of the description. So if the variable `x` turns out to be 3, then purple.png will be the logo, and purple will be thecolor purple for the css.

```
function logoChange() { 
var description = new Array ();
description[0] = "images/logos/blue.png";
description[1] = "images/logos/green.png";
description[2] = "images/logos/orange.png";
description[3] = "images/logos/purple.png";
description[4] = "images/logos/red.png";
description[5] = "images/logos/yellow.png";
var size = description.length;
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
document.getElementById('logo').src=description[x];

var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple', 'red', 'yellow'];

var thecolor = colors[x];

$('.current-menu-item').css({color: thecolor});

$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        color: thecolor
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css({
        color: 'blue'   // change 'blue' to whatever the normal color is without hover
    });
});

}

logoChange();
```

Comment: It is working though when I apply it to a instead of a:hover. Must be that something is overridden...

Comment: @Felix Also, I guess jquery might not let you target `a:hover` as a selector.. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847329/how-to-select-ahover-thats-not-in-a-certain-selector . So what you could do is still use whats there for the current menu item, but for the a, do like `$('a').hover(function() { $(this).css({color: thecolor});`

Comment: I get this error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null". Without "$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({color: thecolor});
});" it's working...

Comment: Now it's working, it was that you removed onload. I put it back and voilà. Thanks for the help!